# Failed to Import External Dependency in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-submit

I have a python script which is dependent on another file, which is also essential for other scripts, so i have zipped it and shipped it to run as a spark-submit job, but unfortunately it seems not to be working, here is my code snippet and the error i'm getting all the time

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
def main(spark):
    employee = spark.read.json("/storage/hadoop/hadoop-3.0.0/bin/employees.json")
    # employee = spark.read.json("/storage/hadoop/hadoop-3.0.0/bin/employee.json")
    employee.printSchema()
    employee.show()
    people = spark.read.json("/storage/hadoop/hadoop-3.0.0/bin/people.json")
    people.printSchema()
    people.show()
    employee.createOrReplaceTempView("employee")
    people.createOrReplaceTempView("people")
    newDataFrame = employee.join(people,(employee.name==people.name),how="inner")
    newDataFrame.distinct().show()
    return "Hello I'm Done Processing the Operation"
```

which is the external dependencies called by other modules as well, and here is another script which is trying to execute the file

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession

def sampleTest(output):
    print output

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #Application Name for the Spark RDD using Python
# APP_NAME = "Spark Application"
     spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Spark Application") \
    .config("spark.master", "spark://192.168.2.3:7077") \
    .getOrCreate()

    # .config() \
import SparkFileMerge    
abc = SparkFileMerge.main(spark)
sampleTest(abc)
```

now when i'm executing the command

```
./spark-submit --py-files /home/varun/SparkPythonJob.zip /home/varun/main.py
```

it is giving me the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/varun/main.py", line 18, in <module>
    from SparkFileMerge import SparkFileMerge
ImportError: No module named SparkFileMerge
```

any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What composes `SparkPythonJob.zip` ?

First, you should check that the first code snippet is actually in a file called `SparkFileMerge.py`.

Comment: so i'm just putting the SparkFileMerge.py file into SparkPython Folder and zipping it to ship it

Comment: so in the archive, the path is probably `./SparkPython/SparkFileMerge.py` instead of `./SparkFileMerge.py`

Comment: Probably you are right but that didn't worked out either, since its a zip file which essentially can have multiple Dependency within the folder, however pyspark extracts it in warehouse folder and load it for further processing. and as i said i'm executing the command ./spark-submit --py-files /home/varun/SparkPythonJob.zip /home/varun/main.py which is irrespective of the fact whether it has one file or multiple, i need all the dependencies from within the zipped file